# CKEDITOR inline editor toolbar on text selection

Tags: ckeditor, inline, onselect

CKEditor 4 can be used in "inline editor" mode, it shows a toolbar whenever the related text area gets the focus. I need to keep the toolbar hidden and only show it when the user selects some text instead, how can I do this?

I'd like to know how to reposition the toolbar too.

Comment: question edited please review and change the status as open(@andrewsi)

Answer (score 3):

you can try something like this:

```
$('#showEditor').mouseup(function () {
    if(getSelectedText()){
    //show inline editor instance

CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
var editor = CKEDITOR.inline( document.getElementById( 'showEditor' ) );

    }
});

function getSelectedText() {
    var t = '';
    if (window.getSelection) {
        t = window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        t = document.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        t = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return t;
}
```